# Rails Nested Fields For not showing fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Expense and Vendor models.

In the Expense form, I'm trying to add a `New Vendor` button.

The Expense model has this:

```
belongs_to :vendor
accepts_nested_attributes_for :vendor
```

The Expense form has this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @expense, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>

...

    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#vendorform">
      <p class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-mini">New Vendor</p>
      <div id="vendorform" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="vendorformLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <%= f.fields_for :vendor do |ff| %>
        <div class="modal-header">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&#215;</a>
          <h4 id="vendorformLabel">Add Vendor</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <%= ff.input :vendor_name %>
            <%= ff.input :address1 %>
            <%= ff.input :address2 %>
            <%= ff.input :city %>
            <%= ff.input :state %>
            <%= ff.input :zipcode %>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <%= ff.submit 'Save Vendor', :class => 'btn btn-mini btn-primary' %>
          <a class="btn btn-mini" data-dismiss="modal" href="#">Close</a>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </a>

...
```

When you click on the `New Vendor` button, the modal opens but it is blank.

Thanks for you help!

UPDATE1

I added `@expense.build_vendor` to the Expense controller `New` section.

Now the fields in the modal form show up.

But, when I submit, it doesn't create a new vendor. Instead it looks like the submit button on the modal submits the Expense form and not the Modal Vendor form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nested fields won't render if there is no associated object - you need to build it in your controller:

```
@expense.build_vendor
```

Also it is quite unusual to create nested fields for belongs_to association - have you considered moving key from `Expense` model to `Vendor` (assuming it is 1-1 association)?

UPDATE:

What you probably want to do is to look into bootstrap modal remote option ([doc here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)). I would create vendors_controller with two actions, `new` and `create` with remote form on 'new'. Then you can point your modal to `new` action, which will take care of modal body. (Note that your modal has to be outside the form, otherwise submit button will submit both forms at once)

When you submit remote form, create action will be triggered. You can write it so it returns json object containing vendor's name and id. You can then capture javascript event 'ajax:success' on your remote form inside bootstrap and add an option to your vendor select as a result of successful vendor form submission.

Hope it makes sense, there are quite a lot of things to do here, but it makes an extremely nice UX.

Comment: A `Vendor has_many :expenses`.  I tried adding the `@expense.build_vendor` to the Expense controller.  I tried both the `New` and the `Create` sections.  Which one is it supposed to be in?

Comment: It looks pretty dodgy to me, if vendor has many expenses, why do you want create a new vendor through expense and not other way around?

Comment: It's for Employees entering new expenses.  But, they may have an expense for a Vendor that isn't in the database.

Comment: Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Ah, I see. I have updated answer with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

BroiSatse has answered my question - thanks!

But, after thinking about it, I decided to just use jquery(coffeescript). I just coded a quick add of the Vendors name and then have it selected.

Here's the code:

```
$('.add_vendor').click ->
  vendorname = $("#vendor").val()
  $.ajax
    type: "POST"
    url: "/vendors/"
    data:
      vendor:
        vendor_name: vendorname
    dataType: "json"

    success: (data) ->
      newOption = $('<option value="'+data.id+'" selected="selected">'+vendorname+'</option>')
      $('#expense_vendor_id').append(newOption)
      $('#vendor').val("")
      return false

    error:(data) ->
      return false
```